# Microsoft graph calendar api delete instance of recurring event

Tags: calendar, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I have created recurring calendar events through graph API in outlook, however, I am not able to find any way to delete a particular instance of a recurring event through Graph API. I have looked all over the graph API documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript

Let me know is it really possible to update/delete a particular recurring event instance and how.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can get all events from the calendar and use the Id of the instance to delete it, a way to get the specific event is by [querying the results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0) or you can use the specific endpoint to [list instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-list-instances?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http):

Send a DELETE request using the following path: **[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/{id}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/%7Bid%7D)**

I did some tests using the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and worked, you can try there
before start the real development.